# How to extract a connected tree of nodes from undirected graph with certain attributes?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, integer-programming, constraints, graph-connectivity

I am working on a problem where I need to extract a connected tree of nodes based on certain attributes while optimizing for the minimum number of nodes. Some attributes of the nodes are known in advance, such as resource capacity. However, I do not know in advance how many nodes will be selected in the final tree, especially the intermediate nodes that ensure connectivity and may act as task-forwarding nodes.

The goal is to formulate a mathematical optimization model with a set of constraints to select an ordered tree with the minimum number of nodes, where each node hosts specific tasks. Selecting individual nodes is straightforward, but I am struggling to write the constraints to ensure that:

1. All selected nodes are connected.
2. The hosted tasks follow a desired ordered sequence.

For example, if nodes host tasks A, B, C, and D, task A should be in a node that comes before a node hosting task B, and so on. Multiple tasks can be placed in the same node if they do not exceed the resource capacity of the node and do not violate the ordered sequence of tasks. A node with task D may act as a root node in the tree.

Most of the existing literature I found online assumes either the total number of nodes in the final tree or the total number of edges in the tree is known beforehand. In my case, it is possible that only a single node may satisfy the required attributes and host all the required tasks, or a set of constraints may be needed to satisfy the required attributes.

Any hints or suggestions regarding how to formulate these constraints are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what you are given as an input. As far as I see there should be some graph of nodes with attributes, some (partially?) ordered set of tasks also with some attributes. Is that all?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "ordered tree". Every tree is partially ordered by the minimum distance from the root to each node. Do you have something else in mind? Also, is precedence measured from the root or from leaves? You said D could be "a root node". Did you mean a leaf node, or that the root of the tree would be the end of the task sequence rather than the beginning?

Comment: @Smylic yes, the input is an undirected graph network, where the resource capacity of each node is given. The attribute of each node refers to its ability to communicate with a set of devices. These devices are not the part of the network. For example, node 1 can communicate with devices d1 and d2. These devices can wirelessly send data to node 1 which is used by the task(s). The tasks should be placed in such a way that task A receives data first, then process the data and forward it to the node hosting task B. The node with task B may receive data from other nodes as well.

Comment: This process continues until the data is forwarded to a node hosting task D. If the data only from d1 and d2 is required, then only node 1 is selected. Depending on the resource capacity of node 1, all tasks A, B, C, and D may be placed in node 1 if it can host all or it may host tasks A and B only and tasks C and D may be placed in node 2 which can host them. It is a kind of generating a data processing pipeline from the node(s) with required number of devices to a node hosting the task D.

Comment: @prubin By ordered tree, I mean tree has an ordered path from leaf node(s) to the root node. As I mentioned above, the leaf node(s) are connected to a set of devices (some of the devices may be shared by different nodes). These devices generate data and send to the relevant nodes. If I need data only from two devices and both are connected to same node, a constraint will select only one node. Next is the placement of tasks in node(s) to process or forward data. If task A and B can be placed in the same node and tasks C and D can be placed in the next connected node.

Comment: My model should give me only 2 nodes. If only task C can be placed in next immediate neighbour node, then the model should find a node where task D can be placed. If the node hosting task D has a direct connection to node hosting task C, then the final output will be with only three nodes otherwise all the intermediate nodes will be selected and we will consider intermediate nodes which ensures the connectivity as data forwarding nodes.

Comment: This sounds less like a tree than like a path (all used nodes connected in a sequence). Can you give an example where it would be a tree with multiple branches?

Comment: @prubin You may call it a multi-source single destination path or a tree represented on the following link. Visually the left-most figure looks the most similar one. https://calcworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/graph-forest.png